# The method setVar(String) in the type DataTableTag is not applicable for the arguments (JspValueExpression)

Tags: jsf, datatable, jsf-1.2

I want to add a list of strings to a data-table and display. The jsp code is

```
<h:dataTable value="#{applicationDetails.showUsersToDeleteList}" var="item">
<h:outputText value="#{item}"></h:outputText>
</h:dataTable>
```

which is working fine as the variables are prompted in the IDE. However while its deployed on the server, I get an error as:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> An error occurred at line: 42 in the jsp file: /NewFile1.jsp
>   The method setVar(String) in the type DataTableTag is not applicable for the arguments (JspValueExpression)
>
> ```
> 39: <h:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{applicationDetails.deleteUser==true}">
> 40: <h:outputLabel value="Enter User Id:"></h:outputLabel>
> 41: <h:inputText value="#{applicationDetails.userId}"></h:inputText>
> 42: <h:dataTable value="#{applicationDetails.showUsersToDeleteList}" var="item">
> 43: <h:outputText value="#{item}"></h:outputText>
> 44: </h:dataTable>
> 45: </h:panelGrid>
> ```

Comment: This suggests classpath pollution with multiple different versioned JSF and/or EL (or even Java EE ... :X ) libraries. What server are you deploying to? Does it already have JSF builtin? What server are you locally developing with? Are you embedding a JSF API/impl along with your webapp?

Comment: I am using JSF 1.2, Tomcat 7.0, JSF is not builtin for Tomcat; all i want to do is display an arraylist type string, in a datatable.

Comment: Problem suggests that runtime classpath is polluted with duplicate/wrong libraries. Logically, it would be helpful for us in order to help you if you list all libraries in runtime classpath (a.o. those in WAR's /WEB-INF/lib) so we can point out offending ones.

Comment: The libraries that I have in the class path are: JRE System Library (jre1.8.0_66), Apache Tomcat v7.0, EclipseLink2.5.2, WebApp (jsf-api-1.2.jar , jsf-impl-1.2.jar, jstl-1.2.jar)

Comment: Problem resolved, only changed the jars in WEBINF, jsf-api-1.2_10.jar and jsf-impl-1.2_10.jar.